# error unmarshaling jaxb from web service with MTOM

Tags: java, jaxb, eclipselink, jax-ws, mtom

I have a jax-ws web service using a schema-based payload.  Adding an MTOM attachment type:

```
<xs:element name="Attachment" type="xs:base64Binary"
            xmime:expectedContentTypes="application/octet-stream" 
            minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" >
</xs:element>
```

ws-import generated java file looks correct:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Contact")
public class Contact {
    @XmlElement(name = "Attachment")
    @XmlMimeType("application/octet-stream")
    protected DataHandler attachment;
```

Using soapUI to send request.

HTTP headers:

```
 Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
 Content-Type: multipart/related; type=application/xop+xml; start=<rootpart@soapui.org>; start-info=text/xml; boundary=----=_Part_96_20541990.1485816424570
 SOAPAction: http://hsn.us.banner.hsntech.com/Level1Request
 MIME-Version: 1.0
 Content-Length: 47624
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEbZS.jpg
```

Then see the HTTP part with the encoded file section:

```
------=_Part_96_20541990.1485816424570"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"
Content-ID: <test1.jpg>"
Content-Disposition: attachment; name="test1.jpg"; filename="test1.jpg""
[0xff][0xd8][0xff][0xe0][0x0][0x10]JFIF[0x0][0x1][0x1][0x1][0x0]`[0x0]`[0x0][0x0][0xff][0xdb][0x0]C[0x0][\n]"... etc...
```

But keep getting this error:

```
[Exception [EclipseLink-25004] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException&#xd;
Exception Description: An error occurred unmarshalling the document&#xd;
Internal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MjAxNi0wMS0wNVQwOTowMDowMA==]</faultstring></ns0:Fault></S:Body></S:Envelope>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: all of wsdl, annotations, http headers and http part seems correct. Maybe it's a MOXY bug. I suggest to try with the standard JAXB Context.

Comment: We are using the moxy feature of the getValueByXPath() function that moxy provides to extract values form the jaxb objects with xpath.  I don't think standard JAXB provides that capability.

Answer (score 0):

The error message basically tells that the value `MjAxNi0wMS0wNVQwOTowMDowMA==` is illegal. If you check it, it is a `base64` encoded date:

```
2016-01-05T09:00:00
```

I do not know if there is another field in the object You are trying to unmarshall. But in case there is the unmarsall process is not able to handle the the base64 encoded value(s). You should check the if there is an adapter needed somewhere.

In one sentence: You should probably have a base64 decoder or check the original service as the decoded `String` is not really some binary data.

(If you insert all of the codes used I could take an in depth look at it.)

Comment: It is binary data.  The issue is, that it should not be be included in-line in the jaxb, but extactable through the DataHandler object that is part of the object definition.  Sorry, but does not really get me much further.  Thanks.

Comment: Try changing the `DataHandler` to `Object` and examine what is set there in a debug session. For me it is still blurry why do you think that the file handling is the problem while the error is showing some base64 encoded date.